# How to get the value of a select's option by its text

Tags: jquery, select

I have a dropdown similar to the following:

```
<select type="select" id="ddl">
    <option value="0">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">Blue</option>
    <option value="2">Red</option>
    <option value="3">Green</option>
    <option value="4">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

I need to get the value of an option when I have the text, *independent of whether anything is selected or not*.

I tried `$('#ddl[text=Blue]).value()`, but that wouldn't work. I don't know what else to try.

Thanks.

**SELECT EXAMPLE FIXED** (I copy/pasted the wrong line - sheesh! ;) )

Comment: (*the title should be **by its text***)

Comment: Why would `#ddlDirector` match anything?

Comment: $('#ddlDirector[text=Blue]).value() .. what is #ddlDirector? you should use #ddl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thfg5/2/

```
var color = "Red";
alert($('#ddl option:contains("' + color + '")').attr("value"));
```

Comment: Anthony's solution is similar, but you get +1 for the fiddle. Thanks, TrueBlue!

Comment: @eventide: Appreciated. Was not sure if first was good enough in this case as they added so much detail to theirs. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code:

```
$('#ddlDirector[text=Blue]).value()
```

1. The `id` is just `ddl`, not `ddlDirector`.
2. You're trying to apply an attribute-equals selector to that element (when you want to apply it to the `<option>` elements inside it).
3. You're trying to use an `attribute-equals` selector, but there's no `text` attribute on the `<option>` elements.

You could use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$('#ddl option:contains("Blue")').val();
```

If you're going to be using it a lot it may be worth creating a function to do it:

```
function getValueFromText(selectId, optionText) {
    return $('#' + selectId + ' option:contains("' + optionText + '")').val();
}
```

Then call it with:

```
var blueValue = getValueFromText('ddl', 'Blue');
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two options:

The first would work if a wildcard search is ok (ex. matches both "Blue" and "Blues"):

```
$('#ddl option:contains("Blue")').val();
```

This will find an exact matches only:

```
$('#ddl option').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 'Blue'; }).val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TEqef/